# What is the meaning of the bold part?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> For me, living in the city was a means to kind of connect
>   with people in an everyday, ordinary way ***without it having to be
>   pretentious***, to feel ***part*** of something and belong.
> <sub>Source: [VOA](http://www.chinavoa.com/show-8246-229683-1.html)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a ‘wild’ quotation, one taken from an unscripted interview, so although the subject is a highly-educated professional you should expect to encounter colloquial rather than formal use.

Although *pretentious* in formal use generally has the meaning Nico gives, “affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed”, in colloquial use it often means merely “involving pretence”. In this case I think that *without it having to be pretentious* is an expansion on *in an everyday, ordinary way*—the speaker feels that urban interactions allow to be who he really is, without having to affect an unnaturally formal style.

The colloquialism involved in *part* is syntactic. In the formal register we have more opportunity to get the prepositions right and say “feel part **of** and belong **to** something”, both prepositions taking *something* as their object. Here, the speaker’s thought runs a little faster than his ability to consruct his phrases.

There is another ellipsis at this point, which is formally acceptable: *You feel part of something* represents *You feel that you are part of something*.

Answer (score 0):

Google says that `pretentious` means:

> pretentious /prɪˈtɛnʃəs/
>
> adjective
>
> 1.
>   attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed.
>
> "pretentious art films"
>
> synonyms: affected, ostentatious, chichi, showy, flashy, tinselly, conspicuous, flaunty, tasteless, kitschy;

Thus, I understand the expression `without it having to be pretentious` means that `living in the city` is `a way` to `connect with people` for which one wouldn't expect to be given any undue credit or merit.